# Python 2.7 Project Directory Setup on Windows7

Tags: execution, setup.py

It seems that there are some issues for me to understand this error, I am trying to run setup.py and create a module or whatever it is called but even tho I installed markerlib it still throws an error.

any ideas?

```
    PS D:\Python_Programming_Zed_Show\Python27_Projects\simple_solver> python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to SIMPLE_SOLVER.egg-info\requires.txt
writing SIMPLE_SOLVER.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to SIMPLE_SOLVER.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to SIMPLE_SOLVER.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    setup(**config)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 145, in run
    self.run_command('egg_info')
  File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 177, in run
    writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "d:\users\arhitect\downloads\distribute-0.7.3\distribute-0.7.3\pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
    from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
ImportError: No module named _markerlib

PS D:\Python_Programming_Zed_Show\Python27_Projects\simple_solver>
```

Comment: error says you have an error in `File "setup.py", line 20`

Comment: i believe error is related to markerlib. if you scroll to the end, you see that its written "_markerlib" but should be markerlib, I have no idea how it became written with underscore, but I think that contributes to an error mostly.

Comment: Yep, and looks like on line 20 you are trying to import or use it

Comment: what is double strange, I did not alter that module/file/package, whatever it is, it is buried deep in there, and I installed and reinstalled but issue persists. It seems that the package is faulty itself?  no idea so far. Would be nice to try to remove that underscore. Any ideas how

Comment: Seems like you have a dependency for that file. Check this file `pkg_resources.py`